# How to align textviews when listviews are null?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, listview, android-listview

So here is my problem:

[image: click]

I have here an `edittext`, 2 `textviews` and 2 `listviews`. The functionality of this activity is a search activity. when you type a certain word or phrase, there can be a result in either in Tools or Articles. My main problem is, when both tools and articles cannot find that word, I want the one in the red box, be something like this:

[image: click to see image here]

but I don't know how. I tried hiding the `listview`s but still I failed. So can you help me with this matter? Here is the `xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar_search"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_back" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/violet"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_search"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp" >
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextSearch"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textArticlesResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_articles"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewArticlesResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textArticlesResult"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
            android:scrollbars="none" 
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textToolsResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/label_tools"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewToolsResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textToolsResult"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabHome"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_home_unselected" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabFb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_fb_unselected" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_search_selected" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabFaves"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_myfaves_unselected" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabSettings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_settings_unselected" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done is to programatically hide the view.  In my case, I wanted to hide the TextView when the content provider returned an empty string.  Do this by:

```
TextView address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
address.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Don't forget to re-enable the TextView when you get a non-empty string by:

```
address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Note that `View.INVISIBLE` will only make the TextView disappear.  `View.GONE` makes it so the TextView isn't even accounted for in the layout.

Comment: so, i have to make the visiblity in the java file and not in xml file?

Comment: You can do it both ways.  However, XML files are static.  I assume you want the fields to appear when the query yields an answer and disappear from the layout when the queries have no answer.  So, doing it programatically in the java file is the way to go